# Get jQuery filter to accept integer variable

Tags: jquery, variables, filter

I'm trying to use the `gt()` filter of a jQuery set.  My wish is to clear all selected elements with a higher index than the element triggering the change event. I'm sure it has to do with not being able to get `gt()` to accept the variable `thisIndex` as a integer and cant seem to find a syntax to do so.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $(".slct").change(function() { // sensitize all slct elements  
        thisIndex = $(".slct").index(this);  
        selGT1 = $(".slct:gt(1)"); // TEST: this correctly selects the elements greater than 1    
        selectsGT = $(".slct:gt(thisIndex)"); // "I WANT thisIndex TO ACT LIKE A INTEGER"    
        $(selectsGT).val(""); // clear elements w/ a index greater than "this"  
    });  
});
```

Comment: The jQuery selector is a string.  You have to build the right string using string addition to construct a string that has your numeric value in it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in your code, "thisIndex" is interpreted as a part of the string. You need to concatenate your integer with the string. So following snippet should do the trick:

```
selectsGT = $(".slct:gt(" + thisIndex + ")");
```